Can't get c++'s seq_cst memory model to work
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync
I took an example from this article from the section acquire/release and rewrote it with bools.
 -Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 3-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 20 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0)

 -Thread 4-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 10)

This article says:

If this example were written using the sequentially consistent model, then one of the stores must happen-before the other (although the order isn't determined until run-time), the values are synchronized between threads, and if one assert passes, the other assert must therefore fail.

Why does my program sometimes print success!!! iteration number:  if I'm using seq_cst memory order?
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

bool test() {
    std::atomic_bool is_started{false};

    std::atomic_bool x{false};
    std::atomic_bool y{false};

    std::atomic_bool x_before_y{false}; // indicates that store(x, true) happened-before store(y, true)
    std::atomic_bool y_before_x{false}; // indicates that store(y, true) happened-before store(x, true)

    std::thread t1([&]{ // -Thread 1-
        while (!is_started.load()) {}

        y.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // store(y, true)
    });

    std::thread t2([&]{ // -Thread 2-
        while (!is_started.load()) {}

        x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // store(x, true)
    });

    std::thread t3([&] { // -Thread 3-
        while (!is_started.load()) {}

        if (!y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) && x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
            x_before_y.store(true);
        }
    });

    std::thread t4([&]{ // -Thread 4-
        while (!is_started.load()) {}

        if (y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) && !x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
            y_before_x.store(true);
        }
    });

    is_started.store(true);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    return x_before_y.exchange(false) && y_before_x.exchange(false);
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        if (test()){ 
            std::cout << "success!!! iteration number: " << i << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            std::cout << "still running" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "fail :(" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


There are no guarantees on how fast the threads will start (or get a time slice to run). is_started might be set to true, before all threads have read it.

Your threads can interleave in any order, and && is not atomic, so AFAICT you can get any combination.

Let thread 4 run up to &&, then thread 1, then thread 3 completely, then thread 2, then the rest of thread 4, and you have both assertions satisfied. Whether this happens with sequential consistency or not does not matter. In this light, I don't see why this is a good example to illustrate the difference between acquire/release and sequential consistency. But what do I know...

You can incrementally improve this (reduce the number of ways the scheduler can surprise you) by: pinning each thread to a core, setting the scheduler class to FIFO and banishing any other activity from those cores, waiting for all the threads to confirm they're running before you trigger is_started, etc.

But you can't make it perfect because the design is flawed. There's no way to make the && atomic or un-interruptible as written.

The only real-world systems where you can observe IRIW reordering (with orders weaker than seq_cst) are some IBM POWER chips and NVidia GPUs.  Definitely not x86; even ARMv8's weakly-ordered memory model is still strong enough to require that all threads agree on the order of any two stores.  See Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?

@PeterCordes A Tutorial Introduction to the ARM and POWER Relaxed Memory Models This abstract shows that IRIW can be observed on current ARM implementations (especially tegra3)

@Alex: Oh interesting, I didn't know any real ARMv7 hardware existed which could do IRIW; maybe what I mis-remembered was none designed by ARM inc (like Cortex-A15).  Interesting that it's from NVidia; some C++ wg21 papers have mentioned their GPUs can do that.  ARMv8 strengthened the memory model to multi-copy atomic (which forbids IRIW reordering).

But anyway, just for the record, an actual IRIW litmus test needs the two readers to do their loads in opposite orders. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync got this right for their seq_cst version, but not for their acquire/release version.  j6t is correct that both observations are possible with some interleaving of program-order, so can happen with sequential consistency.

As @j6t mentioned in comment, example from the article doesn't show the difference between the memory orders

You can upvote the perfect comment, no need to give and approve your own answer.

Or at least quote the comment, or better expand it into a proper answer after understanding it.  Stack overflow comments can get deleted at any time even if answers reference them.
